# Perl Moose augment vs around

Tags: perl, moose

*Trying* to understand Moose:

```
use Modern::Perl;

package FOO {
    use Moose;
    sub rep { say "  <report></report>"; }
    sub doc {
        say "<document>";
        inner();
        say "</document>";
    }
}

package BAR {
    use Moose;
    extends 'FOO';

    around 'rep' => sub {
        my $orig = shift;
        my $self = shift;
        say "<document>";
        $self->$orig(@_);
        say "</document>";
    };

    augment 'doc' => sub {
        say "  <report></report>";
    };
}

package main {
    BAR->new->rep;
    say "===";
    BAR->new->doc;
}
```

Produces...

```
<document>
  <report></report>
</document>
===
<document>
  <report></report>
</document>
```

... the same result. When desinging the "model (object hierarchy)" - based on what I should decide when to use `around` and when `augment`?

Here are probably other (deeper) *things* what i currently didn't understand yet.

Can please someone provide an "more deep" explanation, because reading tru the [Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.1204/lib/Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers.pod) obviously not helped enough...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`augment` and `around` do rather different things. `augment` is designed to make this sort of pattern easier:

```
package Document {
  use Moose;
  sub make_document {
    my $self = shift;
    return "<doc>" . $self->_document_innards . "</doc>"
  }
  # stub; override in child class
  sub _document_innards {
    my $self = shift;
    return "";
  }
}

package Invoice {
  use Moose;
  extends 'Document';
  sub _document_innards {
    my $self = shift;
    return "Give me money!";
  }
}
```

With `augment` it becomes:

```
package Document {
  use Moose;
  sub make_document {
    my $self = shift;
    return "<doc>" . inner() . "</doc>"
  }
}

package Invoice {
  use Moose;
  extends 'Document';
  augment make_document => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    return "Give me money!";
  };
}
```

On the other hand, `around` is used as a replacement for doing `$self->SUPER::method(@args)` because `SUPER` can't work in roles (the notion of which package to check superclasses for is bound at compile-time, so `$self->SUPER::method(@args)` would check superclasses of the **role** (i.e. none) instead of superclasses of the **class that consumed the role**. If you're not using roles, then `SUPER` can still be used in Moose classes just fine. TLDR: `SUPER` is broken by roles, so Moose gives you `around` as an alternative.

Another thing to compare is `override` which is a bit like `around`, but gives you this `super()` function which is perhaps slightly cleaner than `$self->$orig(@_)`. It also has an ["there can be only one"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_%28film%29) feature. If two roles try to provide an `around` modifier for the same method, that's fine: they both get to wrap the method (though the order in which they are applied is undefined). If two roles try to provide an `override` modifier, that's an error.

The implementation of `augment` is somewhat fragile in my experience, so that in my book is a reason to avoid it. Don't try to replace it with `around`, because they do rather different things. Instead, replace it with the pattern used in my first example above.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `augment make_document`?

Comment: Thank you - that makes things a bit clearer :) Asked mainly because learning `Mason/Moose` and Mason's power is mainly based on `augmented` method. (nested rendering of a page).

Answer (score 1):

Using `around` should always be your first instinct. As (Moose creator) Stevan Little [says about `augment`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=947473):

> Thankfully, only a small percentage of people actually grok this
>   feature and of those people only a handful of them are crazy enough to
>   try and use it.

Comment: That doesn't really explain the difference, though.

Comment: Author of `Mason2` is crazy enough to use it very succesfully ;)